# Double Dual of a $\mathrm C ^\ast$ - algebra

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a $\mathrm C ^\ast$-algebra. It is a well known result that $A^{\ast \ast}$ is isometrically isomorphic as Banach space to $A^{''} = \pi_U(A)^{''}$, where $\pi_U$ is the universal representation. Furthermore, the isomorphism is the identity on $A$ (after viewing $A$ inside $\pi_U(A)$ resp. $A^{\ast \ast}$).

If we have an increasing bounded net in $A$, say $a_\lambda$, then the $a_\lambda$ converge strongly to some $g \in A^{''}$.

My question is the following: How does the strong convergence translate to convergence of the $a_\lambda$ to $g \in A^{\ast \ast}$ ? I.e. in what sense converges $a_\lambda$ to $g$ in $A^{\ast \ast}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The topologies that have a natural correspondence are the $\sigma$-weak on $A''$ and the weak$^*$ on $A^{**}$. If $a_\lambda\to g$ strongly in $A''$, it will also converge $\sigma$-weakly (convergence given by the normal states), and so it will converge in the weak$^*$-topology in $A^{**}$.

Comment: By "convergence given by normal states" you mean $a_\lambda \to g$ if and only if $\tau(a_\lambda) \to \tau(g)$ for all $\tau \in (A'')_*$ ? I.e. weak$^*$-convergence inherited from its predual.

Comment: Yes, exactly. That's what the $\sigma$-weak topology is.

Comment: That is good to know. My most concrete picture of it before was the topology induced by semi-norms of the form $T \mapsto \lvert \mathrm{Tr}(ST) \rvert $ for $S$ trace class.

Comment: That's because, for the von Neumann algebra $B(H)$, the normal functionals are precisely those of that form.